# didSelectRowAtIndexPath: transferring the text value to another method

Tags: ios, variables, global-variables, didselectrowatindexpath

- I'm making my first app. Basically I have a sort of menu in a `tableView`.
- When users click on a cell it should take them to another view displaying local HTML content. It works fine.
- However I would like to save the text value of the selected row and pass it to another method (from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath: to the prepareForSegue: method`).
- I have tried a whole lot of things, but it seems that the text variable is somehow local to the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method even though I declared it in the header.

So does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Below is some snip of code.

---

**Header file:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SidebarViewController : UITableViewController {

NSString *rowText;

}

@end
```

---

**Implementation:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath {

    UILabel *mySubNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:201];
    NSString *rowText = mySubNameLabel.text;


    if ([mySubNameLabel.text isEqualToString: @"What is a dataset"]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLab" sender:cell];
    }

    return;
}


- (void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showWeb"]) {

   NSString *myLabel = rowText ;
   ViewController *detailsTVC = [segue destinationViewController];
   detailsTVC.label = myLabel; //rowText;
   }

}

@end
```

- As a final note, it should be mentioned that: *`rowText` returns the correct text string in the first method.
- However in the second method `NSString *myLabel = rowText ;` it returns the value `nil`.

Comment: In didSelectRowAtIndexPath you are creating a new variable rowText, instead of populating your instance variable (_rowText = mySubNameLabel.text).

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

```
  NSString *rowText = mySubNameLabel.text;
```

to :

```
  _rowText = mySubNameLabel.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign `NSString` as `UILabel`. You need to pass like `UILabel.text`.

- `NSString *myLabel = rowText ;`  here myLabel is your string.
- `detailsTVC.label = myLabel;` here you need to pass value to label..

**Try this code:**

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showWeb"]) 
{
   ViewController *detailsTVC = [segue destinationViewController];
   detailsTVC.label.text = rowText; // rowText must be string
}
```

Comment: The only reason I included the line: NSString *myLabel = rowText ; was to include a break line and investigate whether the rowText had the correct value. I implemented your update ass well now. Thanks for the comment.